# Secure kibana access

Tags: security, kibana

I have an elasticsearch server running on my windows server vm, with a kibana plugin.
I would like to secure the access to the following link:

```
machinename:9200/_plugin/head
```

I have seen some solutions, but I didn't succeed in testing them. Is there any simple solution, like adding a plugin to elasticsearch or kibana, or adding some code in kibana sources or config. I would like to avoid the solution of installing a reverse proxy like nginx.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux the easiest solution is to use the apache-utils

[check out this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-http-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-10) for more info.

For windows there is a similar solution for IIS

[check out this link](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/understanding-iis-url-authorization) for more info.